Can I boot an Arm32 OS on the latest RPIs
I am learning ARM assembly, and my final project is to create an OS fully in ASM and C. So, can I run this future OS on latest RPIs that are arm64 ?
Even if the answer is probably no.

Since no one here can predict the future or know what you will build and how; no one can say for sure, but the Pi 4 originally ran a 32-bit version of Raspbian (since renamed Raspberry PI OS).

that depends entirely on your skill

@SteveRobillard said that the RPI 4 originally had a 32bit Raspbian so my OS will Work.
